# How do convert my timestamp to an epoch integer in QuasarDB?

Tags: database, time-series, data-science

When I run a SELECT query on a table in quasardb, I get the timestamp as high resolution timestamp in my program, but I would need to have the value as the seconds since epoch.

I can do this last minute conversion in my program, but I'd like to know if this is something I could do within the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast a timestamp as an epoch number with the cast function, for example, to cast a timestamp as epoch in seconds:

```
SELECT CAST($timestamp AS EPOCH_S) FROM table
```

Supported are EPOCH_MS, EPOCH_US, AND EPOCH_NS for, respectively, milliseconds, microseconds, and nanoseconds.